# org-mode export images to html as figures, not img

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Currently my images are exported with `org-html-publish-to-html`, and they end up as inlined `<img src=''/>`. I want them inside figures, so I'm working around this my problem by injecting the following in my org document:

```
#+BEGIN_HTML
<figure>
<img src="./the_image_path.png"/>
<figcaption style="font-size:0.8em">This is a caption.</figcaption>
</figure>
#+END_HTML
```

This solution isn't ideal, since I may want to generate images on the fly with org-babel, and I'll want to target them with CSS.

How can I tell org-mode to export links to images as figures?

**EDIT:**

It turns out setting the following on my project-alist does the trick.

```
     :html-html5-fancy t
     :html-doctype "html5"
```

However, the output is still messed up because org-mode adds an unnecessary p tag to the image:

```
<figure>
<p><img src="../media/dog.jpg" alt="dog.jpg" width="60%">
</p>
<figcaption><span class="figure-number">Figure 1:</span> This is a dog.</figcaption>
</figure>
```

The culprit is the following function from ox-html. Note the suspicious `<p>` tags:

```
(defun org-html--wrap-image (contents info &optional caption label)
  "Wrap CONTENTS string within an appropriate environment for images.
INFO is a plist used as a communication channel.  When optional
arguments CAPTION and LABEL are given, use them for caption and
\"id\" attribute."
  (let ((html5-fancy (org-html--html5-fancy-p info)))
    (format (if html5-fancy "\n<figure%s>%s%s\n</figure>"
          "\n<div%s class=\"figure\">%s%s\n</div>")
        ;; ID.
        (if (org-string-nw-p label) (format " id=\"%s\"" label) "")
        ;; Contents.
        (format "\n<p>%s</p>" contents)
        ;; Caption.
        (if (not (org-string-nw-p caption)) ""
          (format (if html5-fancy "\n<figcaption>%s</figcaption>"
            "\n<p>%s</p>")
              caption)))))
```

So I redefine the function on my `web-config.el` and remove the

tags, and everything works ok. But is there a better way to do it? Perhaps with an advice?

Comment: Not tested, but setting `org-html-html5-fancy` to t and `org-html-doctype` to `"html5"` should export images to a figure tag.

Comment: I've got those covered, but still doesn't work. Maybe they are being overwritten during export somehow?

Comment: Since you publish the document, did you use the `:html-html5-fancy` and `:html-doctype` keys in your `plist`?

Comment: @mutbuerger thx. That did the trick. It's exporting as figures now. (though the img tag get's wrapped within an extra unnecessary <p> tag, but I can live with that.)

Comment: Actually, the extra <p> tag messes up my CSS, so I've got another problem now.

Comment: Seems to be hardcoded in `org-html--wrap-image`. Nevertheless, I'll write an answer to this question.

Comment: Sure thing. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The relevant variables are

```el
(setq org-html-html5-fancy t
      org-html-doctype "html5")
```

To publish the document with `org-html-publish-to-html` you can also use the `:html-doctype` and `:html-html5-fancy` keys in the plist argument (or in your `org-publish-project-alist`).