# Constructing an advice around org-html--wrap-image

Tags: org-export, regular-expressions, advice

This is a follow-up question from a [previous thread](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27691/org-mode-export-images-to-html-as-figures-not-img)

The function `org-html--wrap-image` adds a `<p>` tag around its contents, as you can see here:

```
ELISP> (org-html--wrap-image "bla" t)
"\n<div class=\"figure\">\n<p>bla</p>\n</div>"
```

I want to remove those `<p>` tags around "bla". My current workaround consists of redefining the function `org-html--wrap-image` completely, removing the tags, but this seems to be a bit of an overkill.

I acknowledge that if I wrap the function with a call to `replace-regexp-in-string`, I can achieve the same effect.

```
ELISP> (replace-regexp-in-string
        (rx (or "<p>" "</p>"))
        ""
        (org-html--wrap-image "bla" t))

"\n<div class=\"figure\">\nbla\n</div>"
```

How can I write an "advice" to do that? I've never written one before, and the documentation for "advices" is kind of harsh on Elisp beginners.

For completeness, here's the function code:

```
(defun org-html--wrap-image (contents info &optional caption label)
  "Wrap CONTENTS string within an appropriate environment for images.
INFO is a plist used as a communication channel.  When optional
arguments CAPTION and LABEL are given, use them for caption and
\"id\" attribute."
  (let ((html5-fancy (org-html--html5-fancy-p info)))
    (format (if html5-fancy "\n<figure%s>%s%s\n</figure>"
          "\n<div%s class=\"figure\">%s%s\n</div>")
        ;; ID.
        (if (org-string-nw-p label) (format " id=\"%s\"" label) "")
        ;; Contents.
        (format "\n<p>%s</p>" contents)
        ;; Caption.
        (if (not (org-string-nw-p caption)) ""
          (format (if html5-fancy "\n<figcaption>%s</figcaption>"
            "\n<p>%s</p>")
              caption)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since Org offers export filters (see `(info "(org) Advanced configuration")`) for this very purpose, I would refrain from advising an internal function. The following will unwrap `img` tags in the final output of an HTML export:

```el
(defun org-html-export-img-without-p-tag (s backend info)
  (when (org-export-derived-backend-p backend 'html)
    (replace-regexp-in-string "class=\"figure\">\n<p>\\(?1:<img[^<]+\\)</p>"
                              "class=\"figure\"\n\\1" s)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-final-output-functions
             'org-html-export-img-without-p-tag)
```